# Symfony2 Unable to Import Resource

Tags: php, symfony, yaml

Symfony application throws the following error when I install vendor files

```
[Symfony\Component\Config\Exception\FileLoaderLoadException]                          
Cannot import resource "/var/www/test/app/config/parameters.yml" from "/var  
/www/test/app/config/config.yml".                                            


[Symfony\Component\Yaml\Exception\ParseException]                                     
Unable to parse in "\/var\/www\/test\/app\/config\/parameters.yml" at line   
2 (near "database_driver   = pdo_mysql").

Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::clearCache handling the post-install-cmd event terminated with an exception      


[RuntimeException]                                                         
An error occurred when executing the "'cache:clear --no-warmup'" command.
```

What's wrong with my import?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your paramteres.yml file is not a valid YAML. It should be

```
database_driver: pdo_mysql
```

Not `=` sign

Answer (score 0):

In case you are unable to use `cache:clear` command as in the error message you can do it manually

`sudo rm -rf app/cache/*`